# Living teachers of the Slabodka approach

Tags: product-recommendation, rabbis, historical-figures

The [Alter of Slabodka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosson_Tzvi_Finkel_(Slabodka)) died in 1927. Suppose someone today wanted to learn the unique "Slabodka approach" as embodied and taught by the Alter. Are there any remaining students of the Alter alive today (they would presumably have to be over 100 years old) that one could learn from? If not, are there any second generation students that are known** to represent the Slabodka approach?

(Note, Wikipedia has a partial list of famous students of the Alter who went on to become influential in many of the modern day yeshivos. I am not simply asking for a list of students. My question is specifically if there is someone alive today who is known** to accurately represent the Alter's approach and can give it over to a student.)

** This is obviously somewhat subjective. The closer to objective the better (e.g. the Alter is recorded as saying that So-And-So follows his path).

Comment: Hi Alex, great question. However, instead of a specific torch carrier, why not study the known facets of his approach deeply first on your own? The Kelm Talmud Torah is famous (where the Alter learned) and it has no comparison today. You could find out about the seder and attitudes of Kelm by learning the stories of R Elya Lopian , for example. Especially stories about how he experienced Kelm. R Dishon once told me that our generation could never accept the daily seder and rules of Kelm; we would not know how to relate. If you can start with Kelm, you are on your way.

Comment: @DavidKenner Actually the Kelm Talmud Torah is often contrasted with the "Slabodka approach" for being more about focusing on slow, minuscule self-improvement, as opposed to Slabodka's "greatness of man" approach. Also, I know you're not looking for books, but תנועת המוסר (vol. 3) was written by his student and some of his other students (in אור הצפן and בעקבות היראה) wrote down some of his teachings, so this might be the next best thing

Answer (score 4):

The Chofetz Chaim yeshiva in Queens NY and its affiliates are explicitly dedicated to perpetuating the unique approach of Slabodka. Unlike other yeshivos, that is their central identity, a true "mussar yeshiva" in the way of slabodka, as opposed to a regular yeshiva with some mussar built in. If you are a brilliant rebbe but not committed to the Slabodka way, you will not be hired.

Another option is the Chevron Yeshiva in Israel. In his later years, the Alter actually left the city of Slabodka and reeatablished the yeshiva in Chevron. It's still around today.

Comment: See other answer about Ner Yisroel. Both are said here to be "explicitly patterned after Slabodka"!

Answer (score 2):

I personally find the approach of [Rav Reuvain Leuchter](http://www.ravleuchter.com) to be true to Slabodka as I understand it, in the sense that he demands individualism and self-reflection, and at the same time intense study and a strong relationship with Rebbeyim, from his students. He himself is a student of Rav Shlomo Wolbe, who is a student of Rav Yeruchem, who is a student of the Alter. But as is evident from his diverse range of students (Rav Aaron Kotler, Rav Yitzchak Hutner, Rav Yaakov Kamentsky, Rav Ruderman etc) it is clear that the Alter catered his method to each student, so presumably any loyal student of the Alter would be doing the same thing. Therefore, "The Alters Method" isn't so formulaic in any event.

Note however that Rav Leuchter's shiurim are fairly challenging, so it may take some time to appreciate them.

Comment: Wasn't Rav Yerucham only a very brief talmid? I thought he only went to him for tochacha

Comment: Because of the limitations of geography I think the standard of time spent with Rabbi was much less. For example, I heard that Rav Chaim Volozener visited the Gra about once a year. Rav Wolbe himself only knew Rav Yeruchem for the last two years of his life, and yet his impact on Rav Wolbe was so profound.

Comment: Does R. Leuchter claim to be following the Slabodka approach, or is it just that his approach appears to be similar?

Comment: I'm contrasting him with talmidim who studied full time in slabodka, or who lived with the Alter (like Rabbi Ruderman, IIRC)

Comment: @robev Your intuition that time spent with a Rav is an important variable determining the accuracy of his reception, but there are many other factors that apply as well. I myself know many people who spend a lot of time with Rebbeyim and have no clue what they're talking about, while there are some who were only zocheh to a few gem conversations with Rebbeyim and have a much more complete grasp of what they're saying. These are extremes obviously, but in concept we look more for the product than the process. Also important to consider, in this particular case, is accessibility of content.

Comment: @EsterLin I'm a little surprised to see Rav Yerucham called a "talmid" of the Alter of Slabodka. My impression had always been that they were fully equal contemporaries, just with very different approaches. And as you say, sometimes they would give one another tochacha. But I'm just going on a couple of stories I heard.

Comment: @EsterLin I do see that the Alter was 24 years older than R' Yerucham, so you are probably right.

Answer (score 2):

Ner Yisroel (or Ner Israel Rabbinical College) explicitly patterns itself after Slabodka. It was founded by Rav Yaakov Ruderman, who was referred to as a son by the Alter of Slabodka. Rav Yaakov Kaminetzky said that of all the Talmidim of the Alter, Rav Ruderman came closest to duplicating his approach.

Rav Aharon Feldman shlit"a once referred to Ner Yisroel as a "kometz of Slabodka", referencing the part of a korban mincha (flour offering) taken to be an azkarah (rememberance).

The source for all this is what I personally observed and heard during my years of attendance and talking to the Rebbeim at Ner Yisroel.

Comment: All very interesting. It is certainly true that Rav Ruderman and his successors chose a remarkable assortment of very different individual rebbeim, from the super-shtark yeshivishe chareidi (say, Rabbi Einstadter) to the Yekki (Rav Moshe Eisemann) to the deep and subtle mekubal (Rabbi Nochum Lansky), and everything in between. All good. Of course, I can't tell if there are many other aspects of Slabodka that I don't see.

Comment: Doesn't "kometz of Slabodka" imply that it isn't an exact replica, just a subset of the approach?

Comment: @salmonius2 He meant that if you factor in yeridas hadoros, it is impossible to fully resemble Slabodka, but the approach of the yeshiva is guided by the Slabodka outlook.

Comment: @MichoelR That is a good observation, and one of the features of the yeshiva Rav Ruderman was most proud of. Their general approach to avodas Hashem and philosophy is modeled on Slabodka, if you pay attention.

Comment: @N.T. "if you pay attention". How can I pay attention, if I don't really know what Slabodka was like?

Comment: @N.T. But I think it's fascinating that Chofetz Chaim _also_ claims to be modeled on Slabodka. I wonder if Chaim Berlin and Lakewood (and of course Rav Avigdor Miller's followers) would also make that claim!

Comment: @MichoelR By pay attention, I meant if you listen carefully, the Rebbeim often quote Slabodka or the Alter when explaining hashkafa. I know Chofetz Chaim makes the same claim, but I am not familiar enough with them or other yeshivas to talk about them knowledgeably.

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy, what you ask. As you yourself said, look at a list of the talmidim of the Alter: they were so different. Rav Ruderman z"l, Rav Yaakov Kaminetsky z"l, Rav Aharon Kotler z"l, Rav Hutner z"l, Rav Avigdor Miller z"l, etc. It was so much part of the Alter's method that each student has his own unique strengths and approach. (There's a famous argument he had with R' Yerucham, the Alter of Mir, on how R' Yerucham was just producing copies of himself...) Could be the "derech of Slabodka" was just letting the Alter do his mastery.
But I used to have a wonderful book, *The Legacy of Slabodka*, by R' Reuven Grossman, about R' Mordechai Shulman z"l. (Seems to be hard to find today.) It gave me a great picture of how very *different* Slabodka was, and how interesting. A lot of the time, the approach of the author was that "You're not going to get this if you're not Slabodka but it's my job to tell you anyhow." I loved it.
But there is a Slabodka Yeshiva in Eretz Yisrael that was under R' Mordechai and maybe there the traditions continue?

Update: Let me just recall (from imperfect memory) a favorite story from the book that gives some of the flavor and ambiguity:

> R' Mordechai Shulman used to say:
> There was a major
> communal issue, where the Chofetz Chaim took a strong position. R'
> Chaim Ozer Grodzinski confided to me that he did not really agree with the
> Chofetz Chaim - and he gave his reason - but he would support him in
> order that there should be unity.
> Many years have passed, and the
> reason given by R' Chaim Ozer no longer seems to apply, while the
> reasons of the Chofetz Chaim continue to apply in full force.
> Nevertheless, I have a psak from my rebbi.

Update: Might as well add another story, *not* from the book. Heard from my Rebbi, Rav Avraham Chaim Lapin z"l, who was in the Telz Yeshiva in Lita before the war. Again, paraphrased from imperfect memory.

> It was bein hazmanim, and I was at one of the places ("datchas"?) that
> some of us went to then. You got a break, it was full of bnei Torah,
> and you would get a chance to see and interact with great people from
> other places that you otherwise didn't get to meet. I was walking
> along, and from the other direction came two young men from Slabodka.
> There was no mistaking them; they had a distinctive dress, a
> distinctive way of walking, and of holding themselves. It was a
> pleasure to look at them. As we passed, we greeted one another. I let
> them get a little further on, and then I turned so that I could watch
> them some more. But a terrible thing happened! They had turned as well
> and were looking at me.

Answer (score 1):

The bumper Pesach edition of Mishpacha 5781 ran a piece on HaRav Yitzchak Grodzinski zt"l, a neighbour of Rav Steinman zt"l and a gadol in his own right who was only niftar a year and a half ago and was regarded as 'the last prince of Slabodka'. It is available online to read [here](https://mishpacha.com/the-hidden-tzaddik-of-chazon-ish-5/).

In the article, it makes mention of Rav Yitzchak's saintly father [Rav Avraham Grodzinski zt"l](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avraham_Grodzinski) who succeeded the Alter as head of Slabodka alongside [Rav Eizik Sher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitzchak_Isaac_Sher). The Alter said about Rav Avraham, "There are many who succeed in breaking their middos, but one
hears the crack. With Rav Avraham there's no sound."

Rav Yitzchak was therefore raised in the Slabodka derech shadowing his father's approach. The article writes there:

> To understand Rav Yitzchak Grodzinski, one needs to open the sefer that he lived and breathed — the half-forgotten work of his father, called **[Toras Avraham](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=103789&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=1617568428030292)**. It’s a demanding work of gadlus ha’adam, the greatness of human potential, **in the Slabodka tradition**. These were the ideas that shaped him in his childhood; they accompanied him as he faced the Nazi hell and defined who he was to the end of his days.

So to answer your question; up to a year and a half ago, Rav Yitzchak Grodzinski would have indeed been a perfect representative of the Slabodka tradition. Someone who was brought up in the world of Slabodka and was raised in the home of the Alter's successor. With his passing we can perhaps reason, that the next best thing is to look to the Torah institution that Rav Yitzchak founded under the recommendation of the Steipler zt"l. Named after his revered father, Kollel Toras Avraham was established in the 1970s.

The article there writes:

> In the 1970s, Kollel Toras Avraham opened its doors and a new chapter began in Rav Grodzinski’s life. Today numbering a hundred avreichim, the kollel focuses on the halachah-oriented approach advocated by Rav Avraham Grodzinski. It quickly became a home to many mature talmidei chachamim, and is considered a leading Bnei Brak institution...**Torah learning, chesed, faith in Hashem — it was as if Rav Avraham Grodzinski’s list of mitzvos, compiled in the blood and fire of the Slabodka ghetto, had converged to become his son’s lifelong endeavor.**